# IBM XMS .Net how do I receive images files like png and jpg from the MQ

Tags: c#, .net, websphere, mq, xms

I have a .net XMS client to receive messages from the MQ. It can receive text files fine. But the problem starts when I try to receive .zip or png files. The problem is that the file saved is corrupted and always intreprets it as textmessage.

```
            var filename = "test.png";
            else if (message is IBytesMessage)
            {
               IBytesMessage bytesMessage = (IBytesMessage)message;
               var messageLength = bytesMessage.ReadInt();
               byte[] uploadPayload = new byte[messageLength];
               bytesMessage.ReadBytes(uploadPayload, messageLength);

               var filePath = _fileUtil.SaveBytesFile(fileName, uploadPayload);
               return filePath;
            }
            if (message is ITextMessage)
            {
                var msg = (ITextMessage)message;
                var result = msg.Text;
                var plainTextBytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(result);
                var filePath = _fileUtil.SaveBytesFile(fileName, plainTextBytes);
                return filePath;

            }
```

The **msg.Text** removes the characerters.
I opened the original png file in notepad++ and find the characters, for example below

```
O-humMkkVøgÆUf¯éÙô
```

I tried also copying the text and pasting the text in an new file corrupts the file. Am I missing something...
gets translated to

```
O-humMkkV?g?Uf????
```

Anyway to read it with the missing characters

Comment: Since images are binary, I wouln't the open file in an application like Notepad that can understand only text. Try viewing in a hex editor like Notepad++.

Comment: hi Sashi, thanks for your input, I meant notepadd++. The problem is that  msg.Text in the code translates it without the other characters

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Send binary data (files) to MQ as type [IBytesMessage](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=interfaces-ibytesmessage#sapibymes).

You should use [BodyLength](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=interfaces-ibytesmessage#sapibymes_getbdylgth) to define the size of the byte[], not [ReadInt](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=interfaces-ibytesmessage#sapibymes_readint).

Change the following line:

```
var messageLength = bytesMessage.ReadInt();
```

To:

```
var messageLength = (int)bytesMessage.BodyLength;
```

The [ITextMessage](https://www.ibm.com/docs/en/ibm-mq/9.2?topic=interfaces-itextmessage) logic works as expected when the content is text.